# apt-get update fails on Debian etch

Tags: debian, apt, debian-etch

I have a debian server running Etch. I can no longer seem to run **apt-get update** properly:

```
root@charm osqa ] apt-get update
Ign http://ftp.uk.debian.org etch Release.gpg
Ign http://ftp.uk.debian.org etch Release
Err http://ftp.uk.debian.org etch/main Packages
  404 Not Found
Err http://ftp.uk.debian.org etch/contrib Packages
  404 Not Found
Err http://ftp.uk.debian.org etch/non-free Packages
  404 Not Found
Failed to fetch http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/dists/etch/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404 Not Found
Failed to fetch http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/dists/etch/contrib/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404 Not Found
Failed to fetch http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/dists/etch/non-free/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404 Not Found
Reading package lists... Done
W: Couldn't stat source package list http://ftp.uk.debian.org etch/main Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/ftp.uk.debian.org_debian_dists_etch_main_binary-i386_Packages) - stat (2 No such file or directory)
W: Couldn't stat source package list http://ftp.uk.debian.org etch/contrib Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/ftp.uk.debian.org_debian_dists_etch_contrib_binary-i386_Packages) - stat (2 No such file or directory)
W: Couldn't stat source package list http://ftp.uk.debian.org etch/non-free Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/ftp.uk.debian.org_debian_dists_etch_non-free_binary-i386_Packages) - stat (2 No such file or directory)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
E: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

My sources.list file is pretty minimal, it just contains:

```
###### Debian Main Repos
deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ etch main contrib
```

Any clues? Have the repo locations changed? Thanks, Joel.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Debian 4.0 (Etch) is an old release that is [no longer supported](http://www.debian.org/releases/etch/):

> Debian GNU/Linux 4.0 has been
>   superseded by Debian GNU/Linux 5.0
>   ("lenny"). Security updates have been
>   discontinued as of the end of February
>   2010.

Etch has now been [moved to archive.debian.org](http://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-announce/2010/06/msg00003.html):

> We intend to copy Etch to
>   archive.debian.org on the evening
>   (UTC) of Sunday 20th June.  Etch will
>   then gradually disappear from the
>   mirrors; the dists tree will be
>   immediately removed and the files in
>   the pool will be removed in groups
>   over the following few days.

Etch has now been removed from ftp.uk.debian.org. You can use the archive by changing your sources.list to:

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ etch main contrib
```

However, to get security support, you would be better off upgrading to Lenny (and also including security.debian.org in sources.list). See the [Lenny Release Notes](http://www.debian.org/releases/lenny/releasenotes) for upgrade instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I took a while after i realized it was a problem with my nameservers .. I couldn't find archive.debian.org

If you ever have this problem, make sure you can ping google by :

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

Then make sure you have nameservers running, you can use google ones : 
This will do the trick

```
sudo echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >> /etc/resolv.conf
```